# using ant in jenkins failed

Tags: svn, jenkins, ant

I had a job in Hudson and I have migrated it to Jenkins but it's failing in Invoke Ant build step.

> **BUILD FAILED
>   D:..\build.xml:16: Problem: failed to create task or type svn
>   Cause: The name is undefined.
>   Action: Check the spelling.
>   Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
>   Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.**

My build file look like this:

```
<property environment="env"/>

<property name="root.dir" value="${basedir}" />
<property name="bin.dir" value="${root.dir}/bin" />

<property name="user.svn" value="xxxx" />
<property name="pass.svn" value="xxxx" />

<target name="checkout-bin">
    <echo message="CHECKOUT" />
    <delete dir="${bin.dir}" />
    <svn javahl="false" username="${user.svn}" password="${pass.svn}">
        <checkout url="${url.svn}" revision="HEAD" destPath="${bin.dir}" />
    </svn>
</target>
```

I'm giving the url.svn as property of Build step like this
**url.svn=xxxxxxxx**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `svn` task is a custom task in Ant, i.e. it is not part of the built-in tasks like `echo` and `property`. You need to explicitly define and import that task.

See this short [article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-use-svn-tasks-with-ant) for how to do it. Basically it goes something like:

```
<path id="svnant.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${svnant.lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />
```

I don't know how it was working before on the old Hudson, but it definitely must have been defined somewhere in the Ant classpath.